# How to change the text of message buttons of push notification in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-push-notifications

I am using Apple Push Notifications and when I receive a new notification, a message with two buttons appears: the alert box says: "View" and "Cancel".

I want to convert it into a one button alert. Is it possible to remove one button and change the text of the remaining one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - see "The Notification Payload" [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html); set `alert` to a dictionary and `action-loc-key` in that dictionary to null and you'll get a single button that dismisses the notification.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - you need to send the `action-loc-key` child property of the `alert` property with your APS payload.

[See this Apple Developer Article for full examples](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW21)